# Handle implementation error with Vivado TCL

Tags: tcl, xilinx, vivado

I have several implementation (each with a different strategy) and I automate running them in  Vivado with the following script:

```
reset_run synth_1

launch_runs synth_1 -jobs 16
wait_on_runs synth_1

# Run all implementations
launch_runs impl_1 -jobs 16
launch_runs impl_2 -jobs 16
launch_runs impl_3 -jobs 16
launch_runs impl_4 -jobs 16
launch_runs impl_5 -jobs 16
launch_runs impl_6 -jobs 16
```

However sometimes one of them fails (low memory or bug in the tools, this is known) and I would like to catch it and do something, maybe try running it again or stop the next steps (for instance if implementation has failed I don't want to export the hardware, because it would lead to another error because it can't find the bitstream).

Do you know how can I catch this problem within my tcl script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but for some reason the result is not among the first ones when googling for words like "vivado catch run failure" and similar, so I'll post an answer:

Based on this [Answer Record](https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/47491?language=en_US) we can do:

```
set isAllOk false

set outputOfSynthRun [launch_runs synth_1]

set runStatus [get_property STATUS [get_runs synth_1]

set runProgress [get_property PROGRESS [get_runs synth_1\\]]

if { $outputOfSynthRun == 0 && $runStatus == "XST Complete!" && $runProgress == "100%"} {

set isAllOk true

} else {

set isAllOk false

}
```